# How to repair a shutter slat (contour shape)

Tags: repair, wood, shutters

The shutter slats (blades) are broken. I do not know how to fix it as I cannot find any replacement part (no results from Google using keywords "contour shape slat") and do not know how to remake one. Now I am stuck on the planning phase of the repair.

[image: broken shutter slat]

I am looking for the instruction/answers/comments to remake to match the slat. I also welcome information on how to buy the matched slats with the contour shape so I can get the repair process going.

Comment: I vote to re-open because OP mentions "make a replacement part". Albeit the solution is not exactly DIY, asking how to do it is certainly DIY spirit.

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus. I agree with you. I type "What is DIY" and Google tell "the activity of decorating, building, and making repairs at home by oneself rather than employing a professional." I am actively seeking methods to repairs by myself, and that qualifies DIY.

Comment: Thanks, but for the record: if you hadn't mentioned "make a replacement part" then I would absolutely agree with the close vote since your post's title and majority of the body content is a shopping question. I'm certain this is why your question got closed. If you edit it to read predominantly "How do I go about fixing this or creating a new one?" then you might have a chance at getting re-opened. Additionally, you made no mention of "repair" except for the tag. Hopefully you use this advice for future questions =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can probably repair it with wood glue. Carefully open up crack, apply glue inside it, and then use weight or champs to press crack close. Should be good as new, or better. If able to get a syringe, can squeeze glue further into crack.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for the easy fix!

Answer (score 2):

That shape was likely achieved by using 2 [molding knife](https://mywoodcutters.com/Molding-Knives) profiles on a [molding machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5P2CyFH09g); [buy your own](https://woodmastertools.com/shop/4-side-molder/model-4000-4-side-molder/).

You need to either find the original manufacturer or a very advanced carpenter in your area that has such a machine. Your chances are probably slim to none.

I agree with [crip659's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/227414/42053) in the you should just wood glue it, clamp it down, sand, and paint.

Even if you find someone with a molding machine I doubt you will want to spend $50-$100 to buy the correct profile for this one-time use.

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing molding knife. It is a new technique that I hope to use one day.